# How can I use OpenCV to find an arbitrarily transformed rectangle in a depth image?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, oculus

I'm attempting to work with a depth sensor to add positional tracking to the Oculus Rift dev kit.  However, I'm having trouble with the sequence of operations producing a usable result.

I'm starting with a 16 bit depth image, where the values sort of (but not really) correspond to millimeters.  Undefined values in the image have already been set to 0.

First I'm eliminating everything outside a certain near and far distance by updating a mask image to exclude them.

```
  cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(depthImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
  cv::Mat depthMask;
  depthImage.convertTo(depthMask, CV_8U);
  for_each_pixel<DepthImagePixel, uint8_t>(depthImage, depthMask, 
    [&](DepthImagePixel & depthPixel, uint8_t & maskPixel){
      if (!maskPixel) {
        return;
      }
      static const uint16_t depthMax = 1200;
      static const uint16_t depthMin = 200;
      if (depthPixel < depthMin || depthPixel > depthMax) {
        maskPixel = 0;
      }
  });
```

Next, since the feature I want is likely to be closer to the camera than the overall scene average, I update the mask again to exclude anything that isn't within a certain range of the median value:

```
  const float depthAverage = cv::mean(depthImage, depthMask)[0];
  const uint16_t depthMax = depthAverage * 1.0;
  const uint16_t depthMin = depthAverage * 0.75;
  for_each_pixel<DepthImagePixel, uint8_t>(depthImage, depthMask, 
    [&](DepthImagePixel & depthPixel, uint8_t & maskPixel){
      if (!maskPixel) {
        return;
      }
      if (depthPixel < depthMin || depthPixel > depthMax) {
        maskPixel = 0;
      }
  });
```

Finally, I zero out everything that's not in the mask, and scale the remaining values to between 10 & 255 before converting the image format to 8 bit

```
  cv::Mat outsideMask;
  cv::bitwise_not(depthMask, outsideMask);
  // Zero out outside the mask
  cv::subtract(depthImage, depthImage, depthImage, outsideMask);
  // Within the mask, normalize to the range + X
  cv::subtract(depthImage, depthMin, depthImage, depthMask);
  double minVal, maxVal;
  minMaxLoc(depthImage, &minVal, &maxVal);
  float range = depthMax - depthMin;
  float scale = (((float)(UINT8_MAX - 10) / range));
  depthImage *= scale;
  cv::add(depthImage, 10, depthImage, depthMask);
  depthImage.convertTo(depthImage, CV_8U);
```

The results looks like this:

[image: Source image]

I'm pretty happy with this section of the code, since it produces pretty clear visual features.

I'm then applying a couple of smoothing operations to get rid of the ridiculous amount of noise from the depth camera:

```
cv::medianBlur(depthImage, depthImage, 9);
cv::Mat blurred;
cv::bilateralFilter(depthImage, blurred, 5, 250, 250);
depthImage = blurred;
cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(depthImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
cv::insertChannel(depthImage, result, 0);
```

Again, the features look pretty clear visually, but I wonder if they couldn't be sharpened somehow:

[image]

Next I'm using canny for edge detection:

```
  cv::Mat canny_output;
  {
    cv::Canny(depthImage, canny_output, 20, 80, 3, true);
    cv::insertChannel(canny_output, result, 1);
  }
```

The lines I'm looking for are there, but not well represented towards the corners:

[image]

Finally I'm using probabilistic Hough to identify lines:

```
  std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
  cv::HoughLinesP(canny_output, lines, pixelRes, degreeRes * CV_PI / 180, hughThreshold, hughMinLength, hughMaxGap);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
  {
    cv::Vec4i l = lines[i];
    glm::vec2 a((l[0], l[1]));
    glm::vec2 b((l[2], l[3]));
    float length = glm::length(a - b);
    cv::line(result, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
  }
```

This results in this image

[image]

At this point I feel like I've gone off the rails, because I can't find a good set of parameters for Hough to produce a reasonable number of candidate lines in which to search for my shape, and I'm not sure if I should be fiddling with Hough or looking at improving the outputs of the prior steps.

Is there a good way of objectively validating my results at each stage, as opposed to just fiddling with the input values until I think it 'looks good'?  Is there a better approach to finding the rectangle given the starting image (and given that it won't necessarily be oriented in a particular direction?

Comment: Concretely speaking, this is a challenging task, and what is needed is a good surface curvature estimator from depth image, designed for smooth surfaces, and that does not require much preprocessing. Preprocessing makes everything smooth, but also makes it harder to distinguish the helmet window from the upper torso.

Comment: [Curves and Surfaces](http://www.cse.usf.edu/~r1k/MachineVisionBook/MachineVision.files/MachineVision_Chapter13.pdf) See 13.3.2, 13.5.2 and 13.8

Comment: Also, it would help if you find a way to either detect, or remove this part from the depth map. [See picture](http://i.imgur.com/HIbhhPL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very cool project!

Though, I feel like your approach does not use all the info that you could get from the depthmap (e.g. 3D points, normals, etc), which would help a lot.

The Point Cloud Library (PCL), which is a C++ library dedicated to the processing of RGB-D data, has a [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php#planar-segmentation) on plane segmentation using RANSAC which could inspire you. You might not want to use PCL in your program, due to the numerous dependencies, however as it is open-source, you can find the algorithm implementation on Github ([PCL SAC segmentation](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/impl/sac_segmentation.hpp)). However, RANSAC might be slow and produce unwanted results depending on the scene.

You could also try to use the approach presented in "Real-Time Plane Segmentation
using RGB-D Cameras" by Holz, Holzer, Rusu and Behnke, 2011 ([PDF](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/robocup2011_holz.pdf)), which suggests fast normal estimation using integral images followed by plane detection using clustering of normals.

Comment: I initially attempted to work with the PCL, but it was an atrocity.  I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and my (fairly large) project uses the statically linked runtime, neither of which PCL supports.  When I did attempt to make a small project that was dynamically linked and tweak PCL to compile in VC2013, I encountered bugs that immediately caused crashes when running some of their demo code.

I'm surprised that a project that uses CMake has such restrictive limitations on their compiler support.

Comment: I'll take a look at the paper, though I'd like a library, not a thesis I have to go implement.  I have made some progress by using Sobel to calculate derivatives across the image.